# Execution of Homomorphic Encrypted Queries on Databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, postgresql, mariadb

I'm going to do a project at my university involving an execution of homomorphic encrypted queries on data bases. Does anyone knows if MSSQL, PostgreSQL, MariaDB or MySQL support homomorphic encryption-based queries?

I found some information on the internet about CryptDB (for MySQL and PostgreSQL), but CryptDB was last maintained 4 years ago. MSSQL has the "Always Encrypted" option that should support that.

Other than that I didn't find any useful information about the support of homomorphic encryption-based queries from the DB above. Maybe I've just didn't find it and it's out there somewhere.

I hope to get an answer or/and useful web links here regarding all of the DB Servers mentioned above.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to achieve? Should only the database itself be encrypted, keeping this transparent to the application? Or do you want to run the encryption in your application such that the database only stores data that looks scrambled to the database?

Comment: If I got it right then I'll be running the encryption in an application such that the database only stores data that looks scrambled to the database. But to be honest, I'll be able to answer your questions only tomorrow after I've clarified the exact specifics of the project. Until then I just wanted to get the relevant information about the DB out there.

Comment: @NicoHaase - [Homomorphic Encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphic_encryption). It's an interesting concept but I don't think it's hit "product" stage in any major DB. E.g. something like SQL Server's Always Encrypted doesn't allow much computation on the *encrypted* values (except for exact equality comparison when using deterministic encryption)

Comment: And even that, that's just "when you use deterministic encryption methods, you can determine equality based on ciphertext rather than plaintext" and has always been true. It's not really what homomorphic encryption is talking about.